# Chamar funções para requição ajax dentro callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Dentro de uma função `callback()` de um click preciso que seja feito pelo menos 3 requisições.

Separei isso em três funções: `(func1(), func2() e func3())`  e cada uma delas faz uma requisição `ajax ($.get)` me retornando `true` ou `false`. Se a `func1()` retornar true a `func2()` pode ser chamada e, se a `func2()` retornar true a `func3()` pode ser chamada. Se qualquer uma das `func()` me retornar false eu não posso prosseguir com a `func` seguinte.

Como eu posso fazer isso, por que dessa forma ele não está retornando true ou false, está retornando `undefined`.

Link no jsfiddle: [Código](https://jsfiddle.net/rjx5o7j9/2/)

```
$('#chamar').bind('click',
            function () {
                $('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
                    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                        // handle the invalid form...
                    } else {

                    if(func1()==false){
                            //aqui ele ja deveria finalizar e não fazer a proxima requisição
                        alert("Função 1 falhou");
                    }

                     if(func2()==false){
                            //aqui ele ja deveria finalizar e não fazer a proxima requisição
                        alert("Função 2 falhou");
                    }

                    if(func3()==false){
                            //aqui ele ja deveria finalizar e não fazer a proxima requisição
                        alert("Função 3 falhou");
                    } 
                        alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas");
                    }
                })


            });

function func1() {

        $.get('consulta1.php?type=dado&action=get', {
                id: $('#id').val(),

            },function (e) {
                e = $.parseJSON(e);
                if (e[0].status) {
                    alert("DEU VERDADEIRO");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("DEU FALSO");
                    return false;
                }
            }).fail(function () {
            alert("DEU FALSO");
            return false;
        });
    }

function func2() {

        $.get('consulta2.php?type=dado&action=get', {
                id: $('#id').val(),

            },function (e) {
                e = $.parseJSON(e);
                if (e[0].status) {
                    alert("DEU VERDADEIRO");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("DEU FALSO");
                    return false;
                }
            }).fail(function () {
            alert("DEU FALSO");
            return false;
        });
    }

function func3() {

        $.get('consulta3.php?type=dado&action=get', {
                id: $('#id').val(),

            },function (e) {
                e = $.parseJSON(e);
                if (e[0].status) {
                    alert("DEU VERDADEIRO");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("DEU FALSO");
                    return false;
                }
            }).fail(function () {
            alert("DEU FALSO");
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Está sempre a retornar `undefined` porque os pedidos ajax são assíncronos, logo só são executados bem mais tarde, entretanto a função já terminou pois não ficou à espera que o pedido fosse terminado. Esse é o principio do assincronismo.

Considere a seguinte estrutura idêntica à que está a utilizar:

```
function func1() {
  $.get(url, { dados }, function (e) { 
      ... 
      return ...;
  }).fail(function () {
    ...
    return ...;
  });

  //<----- Este é o valor que está a ser retornado, que é undefined pois a função não fica 
  //bloqueada à espera que o pedido get termine, simplesmente faz o pedido e continua. 
  //Se ficasse bloqueada à espera então era um pedido síncrono.
}
```

A solução para obter os valores de cada pedido e tomar decisões com base nisso é passar *callbacks* com o que pretende fazer quando o pedido terminar.

Aplicando esse padrão nesta `func1` ficaria assim:

```
function func1(callback /*callback passado aqui*/) {
  $.get(url, { dados }, function (e) { 
      ...
      callback(true); //chamar o callback com true que indica sucesso
  }).fail(function () {
      ...
      callback(false); //chamar o callback com false que indica não sucesso
  });
}
```

E agora quando chama `func1` passa uma função como *callback* que recebe como primeiro parâmetro um booleano indicando se teve sucesso ou não:

```
func1(function (resultado) {
    alert(resultado); //vem true ou falso com base no resultado do pedido ajax
});
```

Aplicando esta ideia ao seu código:

```
function func1(callback) {
    $.get('consulta1.php?type=dado&action=get', 
        { id: $('#id').val() },
        function (e) {
            e = $.parseJSON(e);
            callback(e[0].status?true:false);
        }).fail(function () {
            callback(false);
        });
}

function func2(callback) {
    $.get('consulta2.php?type=dado&action=get', 
        { id: $('#id').val() },
        function (e) {
            e = $.parseJSON(e);
            callback(e[0].status?true:false);
        }).fail(function () {
            callback(false);
        });
}

function func3(callback) {
    $.get('consulta3.php?type=dado&action=get', 
        { id: $('#id').val() },
        function (e) {
            e = $.parseJSON(e);
            callback(e[0].status?true:false);
        }).fail(function () {
            callback(false);
        });
}
```

E o `click` passa a ser:

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        func1( function(resultado1){
            if (!resultado1){
                alert("Função 1 falhou");
            }
            else {
                func2( function(resultado2){
                    if (!resultado2){
                        alert("Função 2 falhou");
                    }
                    else {
                        func3( function(resultado3){
                            if (!resultado3){
                                alert("Função 3 falhou");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#chamar').bind('click', function () {
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

Repare que a cada chamada subsequente aumenta o nível de encadeamento de funções dentro de funções. Este foi o proposito de criação dos [*Promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), em que o encadeamento é feito chamando `then` no fim de cada `Promise` o que não aninha os encadeamentos e se torna mais simples de utilizar.

Também a função de validação do formulário não deve ser definida dentro do click do botão senão vai acumulando vários *handlers* de clicks o que fazem o código executar cada vez mais vezes à medida que clica.

Olhando para a suas funções `func1`, `func2` e `func3` vejo que elas são iguais à exceção do *url*. Então simplifique e generalize uma função para as três:

```
function funcN(url, seletor, callback) {
    $.get(url, 
        { id: $(seletor).val() },
        function (e) {
            e = $.parseJSON(e);
            callback(e[0].status?true:false);
        }).fail(function () {
            callback(false);
        });
}
```

Agora pode usar esta função para os três pedidos mudando apenas o `url`. Coloquei o `seletor` como parâmetro também caso queira poder chamar para outro elemento que não apenas o `#id`.

A utilização seria:

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        funcN( function('consulta1.php?type=dado&action=get','#id',resultado1){
            if (!resultado1){
                alert("Função 1 falhou");
            }
            else {
                funcN( function('consulta2.php?type=dado&action=get','#id',resultado2){
                    if (!resultado2){
                        alert("Função 2 falhou");
                    }
                    else {
                        funcN( function('consulta3.php?type=dado&action=get','#id',resultado3){
                            if (!resultado3){
                                alert("Função 3 falhou");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#chamar').bind('click', function () {
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Olá Isac obrigado por responder. Fiz usando essa abordagem mas acontece que está entrando em algum tipo de loop. Quando eu clico no botão pela primeira vez ele da o erro "Função 1 falhou". Quando eu clico no botão pela segunda vez ele aparece 2 vez o erro "Função 1 falhou", quando eu clico no botão pela 3 vez ele da o erro 3 vezes "Função 1 falhou" e assim por diante. O que pode ser?

Comment: Olhei no Developer Tools do chrome e é como se ele tivesse repetindo as requisições por que tem várias. Quando eu clico pela segunda vez, ele faz duas requisições. QUando eu clico pela terceira vez ele faz 3 requisições e assim por diante.

Comment: @L.J Isso é porque cada vez que o `#chamar` é clicado define um novo handler de click, algo que me passou despercebido no seu código. O que quer fazer é definir o `$('#form').validator().on('submit'` fora do click de `#chamar` e no click de `#chamar` apenas enviar o formulário fazendo `$('#form').submit()`. O objetivo do botão `#chamar` é validar e submeter o formulário se estiver válido certo?

Comment: Isso..antes de enviar eu preciso verificar se o formulário está válido. Eu só uso o 'submit' pq eu preciso validar os campos e verificar se está tudo ok. Tanto que a action do meu form é vazia. O formulario é submetido pelas func1, func2 e func3. Ai pra usar  o validator eu tenho que passar o ide do form. validator()...não sei se daria pra fazer com $("#chamar").validator().

Comment: Então eu não preciso usar $('#form').submit(). Eu faço o envio através dos ajaxs das func1, func2 e func3.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar `func2` em `func1`, e a `func3` em `func2`, de forma semelhante a um `callback`.

Ficará do seguinte forma:

```
$('#chamar').bind('click',
  function () {
    $('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
      } else {
         func1();
      }
  }        
});
```

Implementação da `func1()`:

```
function func1() {
  $.get('consulta1.php?type=dado&action=get', {
    id: $('#id').val(),
  }, function (e) {
    e = $.parseJSON(e);
    if (e[0].status) {
      alert("DEU VERDADEIRO");
      // Chama a func2()
      func2();
      return;
    } else {
      alert("DEU FALSO");
      return;
    }
  }).fail(function () {
    alert("DEU FALSO");
    return;
  });
}
```

Impementação de `func2()`:

```
function func2() {
  $.get('consulta2.php?type=dado&action=get', {
    id: $('#id').val(),
  },function (e) {
    e = $.parseJSON(e);
    if (e[0].status) {
      alert("DEU VERDADEIRO");
      // Chama a func3();
      func3();
      return;
    } else {
      alert("DEU FALSO");
      return;
    }
  }).fail(function () {
    alert("DEU FALSO");
    return;
  });
}
```

Comment: Testei sua implementação e está ocorrendo o mesmo erro que acontece na implementação do Isac. Quando eu clico no botão ele repete o mesmo alert "DEU VERDADEIRO" dependendo da quantidade de vez que cliquei no botão. Se clico uma vez ele aparece uma vez o alert, se mais uma vez ele aparece duas vezes e assim por diante.

Comment: No cick depois do else do func1(func2) eu coloquei um alert: alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas");
Acontece que por ser uma requisição assincrona ele executa esse alert antes de executar o alert dentro da func. Tudo bem. Isso eu entendi. Mas o fato é que esse alert repete-se dependendo do numero de clicks no botão. Ou seja, quando eu clico na 1 vez aparece 1 vez a mensagem alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas"); , quando eu clico pela 2 vez aparece duas a mensagem alert("Todas as requisições foram feitas"); , quando eu clico pela terceira vez aparece 3 vezes a mnsagem do alert.

Comment: Olhei no Developer Tools do chrome e é como se ele tivesse repetindo as requisições por que tem várias. Quando eu clico pela segunda vez, ele faz duas requisições. QUando eu clico pela terceira vez ele faz 3 requisições e assim por diante.

Comment: Que estranho, vou dar uma pesquisada para saber o que está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 0):

acredito que utilizar uma `Promise` seja mais apropriado no seu cado.

```js
var ajax = function (method, url, data) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url);
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (evt) {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
          if (request.response[0].status) {
            resolve("Retorno: Verdadeiro");
          } else {
            reject("Retorno: Falso");
          }
        } else {
          reject("Retorno: Error => " + request.statusText);
        }
      }
    });
    request.responseType = "json";
    request.send(data);
  });
}

var data = { id: document.getElementById("id").value };
ajax("GET", "consulta1.php?type=dado&action=get", data)
.then(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return ajax("GET", "consulta2.php?type=dado&action=get", data);
})
.then(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  return ajax("GET", "consulta3.php?type=dado&action=get", data);
})
.then(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
})
.catch(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
})
```

```html
<input id="id" type="hidden" value="123" />
```

Comment: Como ficaria essa implementação usando $.post ou $.get do jquery...sem usar javascript puro, tem como?

Comment: @L.J no lugar do `XMLHttpRequest` utilize o `$.ajax`, mas não vejo o por que de faze-lo. Ou por outra, se quer usar uma biblioteca com uma `API` mais moderna, utilize o [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: é pq eu já uso jquery no projeto todo, ai colocar só essa requisição com js puro fica meio esquisito...rsrs. Vou testar essa implementação e te falo.

Comment: eu tenho 3 funcs: func1, func2 e func3 como eu chamo elas nessa implementação?